# Sull'uso delle diverse forme dell'imperativo di "dare"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Leggendo questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3899/list-of-uses-of-the-apostrophe-as-opposed-to-the-grave-accent-on-an-a-with-sep) e cercando la [coniugazione del verbo dare](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ITverbs.aspx?v=dare) mi sono accorta che la seconda persona singolare dell'imperativo del verbo dare ha tre forme diverse: ***da'***, ***dai*** e ***dà***. La mia domanda è: tutte e tre queste forme si usano per uguale, in modo indistinto?

Comment: L'ultima, *dà*, non è imperativo, ma indicativo presente (terza persona singolare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secondo il [Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/D/da-dai.shtml), sono tutte e tre corrette:

- > La forma *dà* è la trasposizione diretta della seconda persona singolare
  >   dell’imperativo del verbo latino *dare*.
- > La forma *dai* (da cui è derivata poi *da'* attraverso l'elisione)
  >   ripete, evidentemente, la seconda persona singolare dell’indicativo
  >   presente; la quale nell’italiano, come già nel latino, assume spesso
  >   la funzione dell’imperativo.

Non c'è differenza di significato tra le tre, ma credo che le forme *da'* e *dai* siano ad oggi più utilizzate di *dà* per esprimere l'imperativo, anche per evitare di confonderlo con la terza persona singolare dell'indicativo presente del verbo, anzi sembrerebbe che il suo uso in questa accezione rappresenti un errore (a differenza di quanto dice il Corriere).

Comment: Usare *dà* come seconda persona singolare dell'imperativo è un errore da matita blu. Nonostante l'apostrofo, la forma *da'* dell'imperativo non è un'elisione di *dai*, ma una forma sviluppatasi indipendentemente.

Comment: @egreg: In effetti pare che i linguisti non siano d'accordo tra loro: lo Zingarelli nota esplicitamente «nell'imperativo, la forma *da'* ha l'apostrofo in quanto elisione di *dai*; la forma *dà* ha l'accento per distinguerlo dall'analoga prep. *da*», mentre Serianni nella sua grammatica mette come forme dell'imperativo «*da'* (*da*, *dai*)».

Comment: @egreg grazie, ho aggiornato la mia risposta

Comment: Anche il Treccani elenca *dà* con l'accento con la nota [con radd. sint.]: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dare2/. Finora avevo sempre creduto (e in linea di massima continuo a crederlo) che *dà* con l'accento potesse essere solo la terza persona singolare.